# Continuity of the dilation operator on $\mathcal{C}^0_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, operator-theory

I was wondering whether the dilation operator $f\in\mathcal{C}^0_0(\mathbb{R}^n)=\Big\{g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}. \ : \ g \ is \ continuous \ and \ \lim_{|x|\rightarrow+\infty}|g(x)|=0\Big\}\mapsto f_r\in\mathcal{C}^0_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $f_r(x):=f(rx)$ for some $r\in(0,1)$ is bounded or not with respect to the $L^\infty$ norm.

More precisely, if you consider any $f\in\mathcal{C}^0_0$, and $f^r$ defined as above, I was wondering if
\begin{equation}
\Vert f_r-f\Vert_{\infty,\mathbb{R}^n}\xrightarrow[r\rightarrow1^-]{}0.
\end{equation}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and vanishes at infinity, it is uniformly continuous. So, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. There also exists $R>0$, such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon/2$ when $|x|>R$. Shrink $\delta$ is necessary so that $\delta/(2R)<1/2$. Let $r$ be such that $1-r<\delta/(2R)$

If $|x|>2R$, then $$|rx|>2rR>2(1-\frac\delta {2R})R>R$$
and so $$
|f(x)-f(rx)\leq|f(x)|+|f(rx)|<\varepsilon. 
$$
And if $|x|\leq 2R$, then $|x-rx|=|x|\,(1-r)<\delta$, so
$$
|f(x)-f(rx)|<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: Thank you :D I didn't recall the uniform continuity thing!